# The request failed with HTTP status 400: TLS 1.1 or higher required

Tags: webservices, apex-webservice, website-integration

I'm getting an error"**The request failed with HTTP status 400: TLS 1.1 or higher required**." on "**Add Web Reference**" asp.net window.

Pls, help me out this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because Salesforce is requiring an upgrade to TLS 1.1 or higher.

So you need to upgrade your server to TLS 1.1 or higher

[Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1)

Comment: Thank you Tushar for your response, I have tried with activate and deactivate options but still getting same an error. I'm testing on developer org.

Comment: @GmDeepakChounan21 it doesn't look like you can disable it anymore. You need to raise a case to disable it.